# Can "less relevant" (mainly XAML) errors be suppressed in Visual Studio until needed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, compiler-errors

Sorry about the vague subject line, but to explain:

I am working on a large WPF / C# application with many projects and interdependencies. There are a lot of XAML files which refer to various things like controls, XML namespaces, etc.

If I build the solution, and let's say it contains a C# compile error. That compile error will cause its project not to be built, which in turn might cause other projects not to be built, etc. Now all the references from these projects / namespaces in XAML files will produce further errors.

The result being that the Error List could show hundreds of errors, only one of which is "real", and which doesn't necessarily appear at the top or bottom. So I have to scroll through the entire list looking for any possible errors that aren't XAML errors or project reference errors to find the one C# syntax error.

Is there either a way of preventing this, or a strategy that could be followed for making this job easier? The ideal solution would be that any reference errors or XAML "not found" type errors be suppressed until more 'genuine' errors are resolved, but failing that is there anything that can be done?

I know Visual Studio does give you the option to hide XAML designer errors, but then I'd be afraid they'd never show up at all (or I would have to keep enabling / disabling options) - in any case they'd likely still show up on an actual build.

Answer (score 1):

The error list can be sorted. By default, it's (more or less) sorted by order. But you have several possibilities to find the one relevant error:

- Look at the "File" column. Anything related to xaml files is probably not interesting at the beginning.
- Look at the "Project" column. You typically have an idea of the dependencies
- Reorder the list (click the headers). It's sometimes a bit tricky, but sorting by the first or the second column should order the list in the order they occurred (but note that some projects build in parallel, therefore this might not be deterministic)
- My preferred solution if I run into this problem: Switch to the "output" tab and scroll up. There, the order of errors is really the order in which they occurred.